# How to make a script auto-provide arguments to another without passing via command line?

Tags: python, batch-file

The best way to explain my question is with the help of an example.
Consider a Python Script that asks a question and gives an answer depending on the question.

```
QandA.py

import os,sys,re

ans = input('How you doin\' \(Say Yes\/No\)')
if (ans == "Yes"):
   print("Nice to hear")
elif (ans == "No") :
   print("Oh Too Bad")
```

The above Script would normally prompt the User for an Input, BUT I'd also like it to be called by a Batch Script which will provide the input to the called Python Script.
I'll hardcode these inputs in the Batch File itself (as seen below).

```
call.bat

set ans="Yes"
D:
cd "Automate Answers"
python "QandA.py"
```

Is there any way to achieve this (make the Python Script aware of ans) without modifying the Python Script itself to handle optional command line arguments ?
I'd prefer the Batch Script to run as if it were the user giving inputs to the script from an array of variables.

Comment: Without modifying the python script, you would use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/). But I'm not sure about using it with windows.

Comment: Thanks expect doesn't help a great deal but thanks for bringing it to my awareness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables set in `.bat`, `.cmd`, should show up as environment variables.
Python can read *environment variables* passed in via the [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

```
import os
print(os.environ['ans'])
```

thus you could write:

```
import os

ans = os.environ.get('ans')
if ans is None:  # it was not set, so ask user
    ans = input("How you doin' (Say Yes/No)")

if ans == "Yes":
    print("Nice to hear")
elif ans == "No":
    print("Oh Too Bad")
```

or even do a function:

```
def env_or_input(var_name, prompt):
    val = os.environ.get(var_name)
    if val is None:  # it was not set, so ask user
        val = input(prompt)
    return val

...

ans = env_or_input("ans", "How you doin' (Say Yes/No)")
if ans == "Yes":
    print("Nice to hear")
elif ans == "No":
    print("Oh Too Bad")
```

Comment: I don't see how this meets the requirement that the python script not be modified. But the OP seems to like it.

Comment: well, these are not command line arguments, and they're easier to set in the bat than giving command line arguments

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `echo 'Yes' | python QandA.py` would work. You can add several answers in a fixed sequence, separated by newlines:

```
cat <<EOF | python QandA.py
Yes
No
Why are you asking?
EOF
```

For longer scenarios when you e.g. have to react to changing prompts, you can use [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I believe the OP is using Windows

Answer (score 0):

Piping in a single answer is trivial:

```
set ans="Yes"
cd /d "D:Automate Answers"
echo %ans%|python "QandA.py"
```

But piping in multiple answers is tricky. The following is broken because the batch parser inserts an extra space before each `&` and `)`

```
(echo val1&echo val2&echo val3)|python "script.py"
```

The easiest way to provide multiple answers without extra space is to delay the appearance of the `&` so the initial parsing pass that prepares the pipe sees only a single ECHO on the left side

```
set "+=&"
echo val1%%+%%echo val2%%+%%echo val3|python "script.py"
```